# Close popup when clicking a second time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I've created this table that opens a popup displaying information when you click a td. Each td displays different information in the popup.

What's working:
When I click on a td, it hides any open popup and opens the new popup corresponding to that td.

What's not working:
I want to make it so that when you a) click on the td whose popup is being displayed, it hides the popup (well, makes it display == none), b) click outside the table, hides any popup that is open.

Here's my attempt at the code.

```js
window.onload = function() {

  $('#myTable').on('click', 'td', function() {

    $('.spanClass').html('');
    $('.spanClass').css("display", "none")


    var $tr = $(this).parent('tr');
    var firstCell = $tr.find("td:first").text();
    var didIt = (this.innerText - firstCell);


    //this is me attempting to close the popup if you click on the same td again, but open it if it's not currently open. 
    if ($(this).find(".spanClass").css("display") == 'block') {
      $(this).find(".spanClass").css("display", "none");
    } else {
      $(this).find('.spanClass').html(didIt);
      $(this).find(".spanClass").css("background-color", "#555");
      $(this).find(".spanClass").css("display", "block");
    }
    //this is me attempting to close the popup when I click outside the table.
    if (e.target.id != 'myTable') {
      $(".spanClass").css("display", "none");
    }

  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Head Row</th>
    <th>One</th>
    <th>Two</th>
    <th>Three</th>
    <th>Four</th>
    <th>Five</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Title 1</th>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>9<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
    <td>5<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
    <td>3<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
    <td>2<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
    <td>1<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Title 2</th>
    <td>25<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
    <td>19<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
    <td>16<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
    <td>15<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
    <td>10<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
    <td>2<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Title 3</th>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>50<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
    <td>25<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
    <td>15<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
    <td>10<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
    <td>5<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

Here's my codepen:

https://codepen.io/jackcode1/pen/ZEpbRQq

Comment: Two problems; 1. The function passed to `on` should take `e` as an argument. 2. `e.target.id` will almost always be `!= "myTable"`, because it's almost impossible to click on a table element without clicking on a `td` or `th` or `tr` or `tbody` element first. Your click event handler is targeted to `#myTable` so clicking outside of the table won't trigger that handler. Add another handler to `body` or something and check `e.target.closest('#myTable') == null` and hide if that's true.

Comment: Hmm, that's still not working.

Comment: This is what I tried: 

`window.onload = function() {

   if($(document).on("click")) {
      if (event.target.closest("myTable") == null) {
               $('.spanClass').css("display", "none")
            }
      };
}`

Comment: Okay, I've figured out the one issue. Basically a work around. But I still need the popup to close when I re-click on the same td. Any thoughts on that @HereticMonkey

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function() {

  $('#myTable').on('click', 'td', function(e) {
  
    e.stopPropagation();

    $('.spanClass').html('');
    $('.spanClass').css("display", "none")


    var $tr = $(this).parent('tr');
    var firstCell = $tr.find("td:first").text();
    var didIt = (this.innerText - firstCell);


    //this is me attempting to close the popup if you click on the same td again, but open it if it's not currently open. 
    if ($(this).find(".spanClass").css("display") == 'block') {
      $(this).find(".spanClass").css("display", "none");
    } else {
      $(this).find('.spanClass').html(didIt);
      $(this).find(".spanClass").css("background-color", "#555");
      $(this).find(".spanClass").css("display", "block");
    }
    //this is me attempting to close the popup when I click outside the table.
    

  });
  
   $("body").click(function(e){
   
    if (e.target.id != 'myTable') {
      $(".spanClass").css("display", "none");
    }
  });
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Head Row</th>
    <th>One</th>
    <th>Two</th>
    <th>Three</th>
    <th>Four</th>
    <th>Five</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Title 1</th>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>9<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
    <td>5<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
    <td>3<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
    <td>2<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
    <td>1<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Title 2</th>
    <td>25<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
    <td>19<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
    <td>16<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
    <td>15<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
    <td>10<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
    <td>2<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Title 3</th>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>50<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
    <td>25<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
    <td>15<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
    <td>10<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
    <td>5<span class="spanClass"></span></td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, DCR. It's still not working when I click on the same td twice. i want it to open if I click on a td, but then disappear if I click on that same td again. Any thoughts?

Comment: look into using toggle()

Answer (score 0):

how about this.
use clicking away from the table is the is the first function
clicking on the table is the second. I use the not filter to exclude the one you are clicking on and toggling that one.

here is the pen.  https://codepen.io/pollywog/pen/zYKrdma

```
window.onload = function() { 
    $('body').on('click', function(e) {
      if(!$(e.target).closest('#myTable').length){
        $('.spanClass').html('');
        $('.spanClass').hide();
      }
    });
   
      $('body').on('click', 'td', function() {
         const firstCell = $(this).closest('tr').find("td:first").text();
         const innerText = $(this).text();
         const didIt = (innerText - firstCell);
         const thisSpanClass = $(this).find('.spanClass');
        $('.spanClass').not(thisSpanClass).html('');
        $('.spanClass').not(thisSpanClass).hide();
        thisSpanClass.html(didIt);
        thisSpanClass.css("background-color", "#555");
        thisSpanClass.toggle();
      });
    }
```